# How to programmatically select the root node of Kendo UI treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am a Kendo UI newbie. My Asp.net MVC application has a Kendo UI treeview which is set up like follows.  Each tree node has a unique Id (e.g. EmployeeId which is integer). How can I programmatically select the root node (which has Id of 1) of Kendo UI treeview and the root node's background color should be high-lighted ? Thank you for your help.

```
           var _root = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        cache: false,
                        url: "/Employee/GetEmployees",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { employeeId: _selectedId}
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        hasChildren: "HasChildren",
                        expanded: "expanded",
                        parentId: "parentId",
                        ItemType: "ItemType"
                    }
                }
            });

            _tree = $("#treeView").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: _root,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                loadOnDemand: true,                
                dataImageUrlField: "Image",
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    handleTreeDataBound(e);
                },
                select: function (e) {
                    handleSelect(e.node);
                }
            });

            treeViewCtrl = $("#treeView").data("kendoTreeView");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the treeview's [select](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-select) method, this is how you select the first node:

```
treeViewCtrl.select($("#treeView").find(".k-item").first());
```

If you have more than one root node, then you'll have to use the [`dataItem`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-dataItem) method to get the data item and compare its id with the one you want to select.

Comment: Thank you very much, your codes are working very well.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this little piece of code:

```
treeview.select($('.k-item:first'));
```

This selects the root node. You could also expand it using:

```
treeview.expand($('.k-item:first'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get all root nodes if you have more than one is by using a CSS selector to get immediate children `li` nodes of the `treeview` `ul`.  From there, you can get the `dataItem` for each root.

```
$("#treeview").find("ul > li").each(function () {
     var dataItem = treeView.dataItem($(this));
     console.log(dataItem.text);
});
```